# Rails call back to call external method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We can call an internal method in rails like this

```
after_commit :my_method, on: :create
```

But How do we call an external method ? I have tried

```
after_commit {MyClass.my_method}, on: :create
```

It is not working at all.

THanks for any help!

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: did you removed `{ }` ?

Comment: No sure but should work with `after_commit myclass.my_method, on: :create` or create a private method inside your Model and `after_commit foo_method, on: create` where foo_method is returning `self.myclass.my_method`.

Comment: @radubogdan yes that currently I have for working around. But I was wondering there is a way to directly call outside method

Comment: @radubogdan, removing the `{}`s will actually call the `MyClass.my_method` while ruby is interpreting the class and it will use the return of it as the first argument to the `after_commit` method.

Comment: Yes. I realized that when I've read your answer :) I usually make that hack with private method returning `self.Class.method`. Thanks @smathy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have to create a lambda and pass that in, instead of using the symbol:

```
after_commit -> { MyClass.my_method }, on: :create
```